# SBT can't find tests to run nor compile

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, typesafe-activator

As the title says, I've got an sbt project with one module (for now), but the `test:compile` does not catch any syntax errors (and test doesn't find any tests to run). The way I understand it, an sbt project comes setup with src/main, and src/test (src/it needs to be configured). I'm a bit of an amateur with SBT, but I'll try to give all the relevant info:

Structure:

```
Root
  build.sbt
  mymodule
    build.sbt
    src
      main
        scala
      test
        scala
```

Root build.sbt (I reckon these configs were unecessary but I'm desperate):

```
lazy val `mymodule` = (project in file("mymodule"))
  .configs(Test)
  .settings(scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test")
```

MyModule build.sbt is basically just a list of libraryDependencies (unless one of them is the problem, not sure) like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test",
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-core" % scalaMockVersion % "test",
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % scalaMockVersion % "test",
  "org.codehaus.janino" % "janino" % "2.7.8",
  "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl" % "0.11.2",
  "org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-server" % "0.11.2",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test" // Here because of a bug in Ivy
)
```

Let me know what else I can do to help, it's really racking my brain.

Comment: Where are you running `sbt` from?

Comment: from my project root directory. I can run `sbt` and it does load the project, and i can change the project via `project mymodule`, but alas no tests are to be found/run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With line

```
scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test"
```

you have configured sbt to look up test sources at location `Root/mymodule/test` (rather than at the default location `<base>/src/test/scala`).

So, your options are either (i) to put your tests within `Root/mymodule/test`, (ii) or to remove that configuration line, leaving tests in their default location.

Comment: Well, my tests are at `Root/mymodule/test` so it should work

Comment: actually they are at `Root/mymodule/src/test` so maybe you are on to something...

Comment: So where are these test classes? Under `Root/mymodule/test` or under `Root/mymodule/src/test`? According to your original configuration, the former is the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

I solve with the command `sbt clean compile`

Answer (score 0):

I can see this problem is solved, but I had this happen for a very different reason. I added the play framework to an existing project, by adding the sbt plugin and enabling it, and my tests stopped running. Probably the project was not compiling either but I didn't notice since the tests didn't run. The play framework sbt plugin seems to mess with the source dirs, I had to do this to put it back how it was:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayService, PlayLayoutPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "Coffee",
    scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src/test/scala",
    scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main/scala"
  )
```

Seems very rude!